# How to change value of global variable on any files in TypeScript/Ionic?

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, oauth, global-variables, refresh-token

I'm new to Typescript. Would like to have a variable that can be changed and retrieved anywhere inside Ionic. Had looked at some global variable implementation but only found samples on retrieving values on other class/file.

Basically, I would like to store/retrieve value of a refresh token from oauth2. This will change frequently per each API call and needs to be retrieved too.

Is there a way to do this quickly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need to use the global scope then use the declare statement to access variables in the global scope:

```
declare var test: any;

class AnyThing {
    changeTest(): void {
        test = 'something';
    }
}

let at = new AnyThing();
at.changeTest();
console.log(test);
```

However, you can often use other approaches to share a variable in your application without polluting the global scope. The Angular/Ionic approach would be to create a service that can be injected anywhere where you can update or change the variable. [Check out the Angular docs for an example of a service](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4).

Another simple approach would be to use localstorage or sessionstorage to share data.

```
//Set the key 'test' to the value 'something'
localStorage.setItem('test', 'something');

//Retreive the key 'test'
localStorage.getItem('test');
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. localStorage is what I'm looking for! Got hard time using ionic's storage, but your approach is much simpler. Thanks for this. You're a life saver!